# What is the distribution of $\frac{1}{1-\rho_{\max}}$? Where $\rho_{\max} = \max\{X_1,...,X_d\}$, $X_i$ ~ Unif[0,1]

Tags: probability, random-variables

The distribution of $\rho_{\max}$ is a classic order statistics problem ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18433/how-do-you-calculate-the-probability-density-function-of-the-maximum-of-a-sample)), and it follows beta distribution. Therefore $1-\rho_{\max}$ is also straight forward.

I can use transformation to find the probability density function of $\frac{1}{1-\rho_{\max}}$, and I'm curious if it follows a certain (familiar) distribution?

Comment: Fyi, $1-\rho_{max}=\rho_{min}$

Comment: If you show the density of that random variable (call it $Z$), then someone might recognize it as a familiar distribution.  I believe the density is $n (z-1)^{n-1} z^{-n-1}$ for $z>1$ and zero elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

$$\frac{1}{1-\rho_{\text{max}}}\sim FP(1,1,1,1,n)$$

where $FP$ denotes **Feller-Pareto** distribution, and

$$\frac{1}{1-\rho_{\text{max}}}\sim B'(n,1)+1$$

where $B'$ denotes inverted beta distribution.

We know that

$$1-\rho_{\text{max}}=\rho_{\text{min}}\sim B(1,n)$$

so let us check

$$\frac{1}{1-\rho_{\text{max}}}=\frac{1}{\rho_{\text{min}}}.$$

From the definition of inverted beta distributions,

$$\frac{\rho_{\text{min}}}{1-\rho_{\text{min}}}\sim B'(1,n).$$

From a property of inverted beta distributions, we have $\frac{1}{B'(1,n)}\sim B'(n,1),$ which gives

$$\frac{1-\rho_{\text{min}}}{\rho_{\text{min}}}\sim B'(n,1),$$

or

$$\frac{1}{\rho_{\text{min}}}\sim B'(n,1)+1.$$

To get the first, note that

$$FP(μ, σ, γ, γ_1, γ_2) \sim \mu + \sigma(Y^{-1}-1)^\gamma$$

where $Y \sim B(γ_1, γ_2).$

Answer (score 0):

For $\frac1{1-\rho_{\max}}$ I don't think it has a familiar distribution. However, $\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}$ has an [inverted beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution).

Comment: $1/(1-x)=x/(1-x)+1$